# Will PHP included html content affect my seo?

Tags: seo

Today i purchase a small CMS system. With this CMS i can transform my static site into an editable page. I have to cut the content which i want to make editable, and paste it into the admin area. The script will generate a new html with this content. Than i have to include this html to the place where the original content was.

I need some advise about SEO.

I have many text on my site, 'coz i wanna my site in search engines good position.

- But if i delete my text and replace them with  includes, how this will affect to SEO? (bots read my source, or read my source after php include my text-content?)
- May i instert the newly generated HTML files into my sitemap.xml?
- May i exclude bots from my CMS directory  (this directory contain the generated html files too) via htaccess?

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But if i delete my text and replace them with includes, how this will affect to SEO? (bots read my source, or read my source after php include my text-content?)

Not at all, PHP is server side, and thus it's outputed HTML will have the same SEO affect as your previous html files

> May i instert the newly generated HTML files into my sitemap.xml?

Yes

> May i exclude bots from my CMS directory (this directory contain the generated html files too) via htaccess?

Yes, in your robots txt file disallow them from accessing the folder. Also most likely your cms is password protected so the bots shouldn't have access

Comment: But if i exclude my CMS directory, and i instert my generated html to my sitemap.xml, the bots can read this files? Or i have to exclude all my CMS files without the sub-directory which contain my htmls?

Comment: Usually the administration of a cms is located in a specific folder `/wp-admin`, `/administrator` or `/perch` while the other content is located somewhere else. don't include those files in your sitemap