# Better use of html li tag for seo optimization

Tags: html, seo

If I code like Example1,how will this affect seo?(I mean the content type of the third li tag's content is different from other's.)

Example1:

```
<ul>
  <li>some description of html</li>
  <li>some description of css</li>
  <li>
    other update operation here...
    <input></input>
    <button></button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

I think Example2 should be ok.

Example2:

```
<ul>
  <li>some description of html</li>
  <li>some description of css</li>
  <li>some description of js</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @DipeshParmar You're totally wrong ... SEO **used to** work on these, but is not for really long time now.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek so please let us know..cause i was wondering too,

Comment: This question is not a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772368/will-php-included-html-content-affect-my-seo

Answer (score 3):

A bit bigger picture is necessary to decide, but I think you should not really care about that. Just make your site useful to the user:

Need an input and a button as third item in list? Put it there! It's rather common situation, especially when you use unordered lists instead of table-based layout and the last *cell* contains some *action* buttons/inputs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.You said "SEO used to work on these",could you please give me some clues of that.,thank you for your answer.You said "SEO used to work on these",could you please give me some clues of that.

Comment: That was in response to Dipesh Parmar's comment about keyword and description meta tags.